# How to find out the IP address who performed DML operations on a certain table in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to find out the IP address who performed DML operations on a certain table in Postgres?

Comment: That's not possible. Btw: Postgres 9.1 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  - you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: version does not matter

Answer (score 1):

Ahead of time, you can set up an audit trigger which records the inet_client_addr().  [For example](https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/audit-trigger/blob/master/audit.sql).

Or you can use the server log file, by setting log_statement='mod' and making sure that log_line_prefix records the remote host.

If you are trying to do this after the fact without having first set up something like one of the above, then no.

Answer (score 0):

One way is you can modify your code to store the IP address of the user machine into one of the columns.(Basically in one of the common table)